# Verifying password in ASP.Net Identity 2 using LDAP as datastore

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ldap, asp.net-identity-2

I'm implementing authentication for a ASP.Net MVC5 Page using ASP.Net Identity 2 and LDAP as storage for the users. I'm not using OWIN.

I started to create my own IUserStore deriving from `IUserPasswordStore`. This interface needs to implement three methods:

- `GetPasswordHashAsync`
- `SetPasswordHashAsync`
- `HasPasswordAsync`

I'm now wondering how to verify the passowrd for a user since `UserManager` only offers a `CheckPasswordAsync` method which accepts the user object and the entered password. My assumption how this works is as following:

1. This method uses the `Passwordhasher`and it's `VerifyHashedPassword` method.
2. `VerifyHashedPassword`then receives the hashed password provided by `IUserStore`s `GetPasswordHashAsync` method.
3. Therefore I could implement my own passwordhasher and verify the provided password against the saved password hash

If this assumptions are right and this could be a solution I'm wondering about security. What is the correct place for performing hashing and verifying this hashes... should all happen inside the LDAP (the solution wouldn't work) or is it better to hash a password before sending to an LDAP for storage and then check the hashed password by myself?
Could retrieving passwordhashes from the LDAP be an attack vector for at least fetching the hashes?

Does a complete different approach within ASP.Net Identity exist for authentication against an LDAP? I know that there is a possibility for authenticating against an external mechanism, but I expect that this is designt for login by Google/Facebook ect. which present an own credentials input form and therefore not suitable for LDAP.

Comment: AFIK, and if I understand what you are attempting to do, the password within Microsoft Active Directory is not a hash but an encrypted value that cannot be retrieved. LDAP offers a compare or the proper method to verify the password against LDAP with a bind request.

Comment: It's not AD which I will access (that's why I wrote LDAP). Actually it's OpenLDAP which so far I understood only does hashing (one can choose over config which algorithm should be used). I also know that bind would be the official way intedended by LDAP, but that's also part of the question. I don't see the place where to perform the bind sind the Identity interfaces and classes don't offer a simple "login"-method. As far as I unterstand they split it up to "find user" and "verify password".